# Calling ps on Linux from Java

Tags: java, linux

In Java, I start one new Process using Runtime.exec(), and this process in turn spawns several child processes.

I want to be able to kill all the processes, and have previously been trying `process.destroy()` and `process.destroyForcibly()` - but the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) say that `destroyForcibly()` just calls `destroy()` in the default implementation and `destroy()` may not kill all subprocesses (I've tried and it clearly doesn't kill the child processes).

I'm now trying a different approach, looking up the PID of the parent process using the method suggested [here](http://www.golesny.de/p/code/javagetpid) and then calling `ps` repeatedly to traverse the PIDs of child processes, then killing them all using `kill`. (It only needs to run on Linux).

I've managed the first bit - looking up the PID, and am trying the following command to call ps to get the child PIDs:

```
String command = "/bin/ps --ppid " + pid;
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
process.waitFor();
```

Unfortunately the 2nd line above is throwing an IOException, with the following message: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/ps --ppid 21886": error=2, No such file or directory`

The command runs fine if I paste it straight into the terminal on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using Java 9+ see [`ProcessHandle.descendants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#descendants()). The `Process` class also has a `descendants()` method (by default simply calls `toHandle().descendants()`).

Comment: Only on Java 8 but good to know for future, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the command you wish to run this way is always destined to fail.

Since `Process` does not effectively run a shell session, the command is basically handed over to the underlying OS to run. This means that it'll fail, since the path to t he program to be executed (in this case `ps`), is not the full one hence the error you're getting.

Also, testing whether your command works using a terminal is not correct. Using a terminal contains the notion of performing an action with an active logged in user with a correct path etc etc. All the above are not the case though when running a command through `Process` as these are not taken into consideration.

Furthermore, you also need to account for cases where the actual java application could be running under a different user, with a different set of permissions, paths etc.

In order for your to fix this, you can simply do either of the following:

1) Invoke your `ps` command using the full path to it (still not sure if it would work)

2) Change the way your create the `Process` object into something like: `p = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command).start();`

The second, will effectively run a bash session, passing in the `ps` command as an argument thus obtaining the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

```

```
String line = "AcroRd32.exe /p /h " + file.getAbsolutePath();
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```

```

Comment: I don't think that suggesting to someone to use a third party library for something that has native jdk support is a good idea.